# Oauth throws "invalid_grant: user hasn't approved this consumer" randomly for Community Login profile

Tags: oauth2, jwt

I have an OAuth JWT Bearer token flow set up like this:

- Admin approved users are pre-authorized
- all profiles added to approved list
- Relax IP restrictions
- api, refresh_token/offline_access oauth scopes defined

It works fine for System Administrator, but fails randomly for Customer Community Login license user with: `invalid_grant "user hasn't approved this consumer"`. Then it works, and after 5 minutes fails again.

It doesn't seem like I hit the login limit (from Setup -> Company Information related list: Customer Community Logins: Allowance **10,000** Amount Used :**4,661**  5/16/2019 7:59 PM)

There are a few similar questions out there but I still could not find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was the audience oauth parameter for **community users must be community url**, instead of `test.salesforce.com` on sandbox.
According to docs:

> The audience (aud) identifies the authorization server as an intended audience. Use the authorization server’s URL for the audience value: https://login.salesforce.com, https://test.salesforce.com, or https://community.force.com/customers if implementing for a community.

It was a bit misleading because using `test.salesforce.com` failed only sometimes.